# Calculate Euclidian distances between elements of two data sets

Tags: r, dataframe, distance

I have two data sets of the same size:

```
>df1

    c  d  e
a   2  3  4
b   5  1  3

>df2

   h  i  j
f  1  1  2
g  0  4  3
```

I need to calculate Euclidian distances between the same elements of these data sets to get:

```
   c  d  e
a  1  2  2
b  5  3  0
```

I have tried using `dist(rbind(df1, df2))`, but the result gave only one entry.

I have to perform this operation with numerous data sets, that's why your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, the term "Euclidian Distance" in reference to scalars would mean just taking the absolute difference of the numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#One_dimension . Luckily you provided expected output to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh, no, I actually meant the Euclidian distance as an absolute difference, but provided a wrong example. Thank you a lot for pointing it out! Thus I don't have a solution to my question yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your update the solution would be to do absolute value (`abs`) of the difference:

```
abs(df1 - df2)
```

And you could make a function if you want to repeat the process a lot:

```
myfunc1 <- function(x1,x2){
  abs(x1 - x2)
}
myfunc1(df1, df2)
```

The output looks as intended:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    2
[2,]    5    3    0
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will work if the data frames are all numeric and have the same column and row numbers.

```
df3 <- abs(df1 - df2)
df3
#   c d e
# a 1 2 2
# b 5 3 0
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "    c  d  e
a   2  3  4
                  b   5  4  3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = 1)

df2 <- read.table(text = "    h  i  j
f  1  1  2
                  g  0  1  3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = 1)
```